# Remove default background of Icon in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was developing some app, where I add an icon using Jetpack compose as UI develoment library, and I find out the icon have some border due to I add a Background to the icon.

The code is this:

```
  Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize()
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_check_circle_outline),
                    contentDescription = "checkIcon",
                    tint = DarkGreen,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(
                            color = Color.White,
                            shape = CircleShape
                        )
                        .clip(CircleShape)
                        .border(BorderStroke(4.dp, DarkGreen), CircleShape)
                        .align(Alignment.Center)
                        .size((Utils.convertPixelsToDp((width/4).toFloat(),context = context).dp))
                )
            }
```

Realize I'm adding a white background, to my icon which is green, and I add a border which their main goal is cover the white border shown by the icon.

It's shown like this:

[image]

As you can check there is a tiny border around the icon, which I try to remove adding the border using the same color of the background.

I don't know why this border is added in firts time to the icon, and I don't know how to remove this behaviour neither.

Do you know some way to remove this border. Take thanks in advance !7

[EDIT]

I try adding "padding(PaddingValues(0.dp))", to Icon component, but doesn't remove the border either

Comment: Just change the icon drawable to remove outline

Comment: But I need that drawable. What are you guessing exactly?

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```
contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
```

Comment: Where should I apply contentPadding, because Icon and Box doesn't have that attribute. I guess just LazyColumn have

Comment: I give a try to your soluction adding padding atribute to Icon component, but doesn't work either

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).